# Internet connectivity issues in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet, home-networking

Info:

- Desktop. Windows 8.
- I have two network adapters on my computer. One is a USB adapter, and the other is internal (disabled currently).
- I have 4 out of 5 bars of signal on my wireless adapter for my home network.

Issues:
Pages will load half-way and then quit loading. Works for 1 minute, stops for 1 minute. Keep getting "error connection reset" or "connection was interrupted." It's like it works, and then stops, then works, then stops.

What I have tried:

1. Disabling one wireless adapter and using the other, and then vice
   versa.
2. Resetting the wireless router and modem.
3. Switching from
   Chrome to IE (ugh)
4. Rebooting the computer

What I think the problem is:
Software: Windows 8 or the device drivers. Why do I think this: My iPad at the same location in the house connects to the internet just fine and doesn't have these issues. So does my Android phone.  I never lose connection with either one. Also, my hardware seems to be able to connect to the network at good strength.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried deleting cache and cookies and other browsing data?

Comment: Driver issues probably?

Comment: Have you tried to update  your network drivers? Check them on manufacturers site if they have available then download them and install. Also if you have not install them as Windows 8 install them automatically, but maybe at this time default drivers install by Windows 8 is not working properly. So try to install the manufacturers network driver. Or driver of Windows 7 maybe work.

Comment: I think I am having similar issues too, but I find it hard to diagnose as I don't know if its because there is too much contention on the wireless network, the internet connection is too slow, a driver issue, or something with Windows 8.